# create random sample conditionally using a file

Tags: python-3.x, conditional-statements, sampling, multiple-conditions

I am trying to assign reviewers to projects with the condition that the author of the project cannot be assigned as a reviewer to a project in their own portfolio.

I created a dataset with variables named project and portfolio. I have an array with the names of the individuals.

Please be kind, as I am learning Python on my own on the job, using Jupyter Notebook, python 3. I copied this code from other places and put it together.  I have been at this all day.  My superior wants error free code by the end of the week. I am desperate!!!

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
!pip install pandas
    dir_path = "path/to/filename.csv"    

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(dir_path,index_col=0)
df.head

import random
     random.seed(25, 2) #sets the first random number for reproducibility
     random.randint(100, 250) #random integer 100 to 250
```

Update 1 (works, thanks Ken!):

```
import pandas as pd

# Load  dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(dir_path, index_col = 0)
first = df["portfolio"] 
print(first)     

Update2  # Select 6 random projects for Moi which are not "XXX"
#random dataframe
import numpy as py
df2 = pd.read_csv(dir_path, skiprows=1)
np.random.seed(100)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(6,2)), columns=list('project portfolio') if ((portfolio == "XYZ") or (portfolio == "ABC") or (portfolio == "MKZ") or (portfolio == "BNZ")) 
print (df2)
```

---

```
Error message 
File "<ipython-input-29-0ee5224a45db>", line 7
    print (df2)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I daresay this is a simple mistake.

Comment: You're missing a `)` at the end of the section with `df1 =`, on the line that starts with `index`.

Comment: Thanks, Ken.  Fixed a few other things and that segment of the code now works..

Comment: Following Update2 -- see code above, I received the following error                                 
    ----Error message File "<ipython-input-29-0ee5224a45db>", line 7 print (df2) ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: The line before `print(df2)` has unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: Since Pandas is working, your installation here is not a problem, however, you'll have a better modern Jupyter experience going forward if you cease to use an exclamation point in conjunction with install commands. Specifically, it should be `%pip install pandas`. In 2019 the magic version of the install commands were added to insure the installations occur in the environment where the kernel backing the active notebook is running. The exclamation point doesn't do that and so can at times lead to issues. ....

Comment: <continued> See more about the modern `%pip install` command [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). [The second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues.

Comment: Both the issues you've encountered are because you're not matching symbols that have to be matched. Here's a tip: Get in the habit of typing a `)` **immediately** after typing the `(`, and then using the left arrow key to move back to put your cursor between them. Do the same with `[]` and `{}`. Keep doing this until you've established in your mind that those **always, with no exceptions**. have to be used in pairs. And when you get an error like these, get in the habit of counting the pairs - count all the `(`, and then go back and count all the `)` - the counts should be equal.